# Easy way of daemonizing in CentOS 5.4

Tags: linux, shell, centos, daemon

I know there is a program called upstart that can make it easy to make small daemons. I can't get this program to configure on CentOS. I get all sort of errors concerning pkg-congfig, libnih, and dbus.

I am working on a node.ja application and this is a pain to start and stop all the time, so I want to create a deamon for this which makes it easy to start and stop.

**Update 1**
I will give a small example of what i need for this project, I hope someone can help with this.

To start the node.js application I have to type in SSH:

```
# node /path-to-file/filename.js
```

Now when I execute this the terminal freezez, i have to press CTRL + Z (pc) to get input back.

Now when i changed something in the file I have to reload it again

I need to:

```
# killall -9 node
```

This kills all the node applications that are running

Next i have to start the script again

```
# node /path-to-file/filename.js
```

I want to just type

```
# myapp restart
```

And everything is done. This type of setup would save me lots of time

**Update 2**
I found a program called monit. This works nice, and automatically starts the application in case of a crash, which is good. It also has a nice web interface which is also handy.

I can type

```
# monit myapp start(start/stop/restart)
```

This works fine. There is only one downside, and this is a major downside. When i start the myapp application, it does not display the compile errors node.js throws. So when it fails to start I will not know what the reason is. I have to type the whole '# node /path-to-file/filename.js' again to check the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need anything special to make a daemon, really. Any program in any language can "daemonize" itself. Alternatively, you can daemonize an existing program with a small shell script wrapper (for instance the /etc/init.d program launcher can take care of it).

Typically, a daemon has the following properties :

- working directory must be /
- STDIN must be /dev/null
- STDOUT and STDERR must be either /dev/null or log files
- the parent ID should be init ( 1 ), easily achieved by forking then letting the parent exit.

**Update 1**

Monit basically takes care of the gory details I gave here. For the details about STDIN/STDOUT, /dev/null etc. these are basic Unix concepts so I guess you'll need to dig into this sooner or later. See for instance this [Unix introduction](http://www.mhpcc.edu/training/vitecbids/UnixIntro/UnixIntro.html).

**Update 2**

A shell script that daemonize a program would look like the following. Note that this will not work for programs that stay in the foreground.

```
#!/bin/sh

DAEMON=/some/program/to/run
PARAMETERS="parameters to my program"
LOGFILE=/var/log/somefile.log

start() {
    echo -n "starting up $DAEMON"
    RUN=`cd / && $DAEMON $PARAMETERS > $LOGFILE 2>&1`

    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Done."
    else
        echo "FAILED."
    fi
}

stop() {
    killall $DAEMON
}

status() {
    killall -0 $DAEMON

    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Running."
    else
        echo "Not Running."
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    start
    ;;

    restart)
    stop
    sleep 2
    start
    ;;

    stop)
    stop
    ;;

    status)
    status
    ;;

    *)
    echo "usage : $0 start|restart|stop|status"
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Ok i am new to linux, so I don't know what all those tings are. Can you maybe give me a little example on how to achieve this. I will edit the question a little and maybe you can help me with this particular type of setup, because i have no idea what stdin, etc are.

Comment: Ok so basically I just create a file(myapp), and just add #!/bin/sh to the top of the line. And when I type the filename it will run as a program?

Comment: Thank you this will get me started on the program. Thank you for the help. Accepted answer

Comment: Good answer, though I would add that the parent process should ignore SIGCHLD in order for init to immediately inherit the orphan process and not leave a zombie in the process table. This is easily done in scripts using the NOHUP command, but like you said, tie up all 3 standard IO as well.

Comment: This works great. I now have full control over the start and stop of the execution. This will save me a huge amount of time.

Comment: You're welcome :) you can use this script as /etc/init.d/yourapp and use your application as a full-fledged service from now. Error messages will go to the log file ( /var/log/whatever).

Comment: Simply closing stdin and backgrounding works as well: ``myprog 1<&- &``. Now you have a daemon.

Comment: @woot, chdir to /root is essential to not prevent unmounting something inadvertently.

Answer (score 3):

To start a script in non-interacting session, use `nohup` (it will detach your process in a standalone term).

To make your script executable, use `chmod ugoa+x <script_name>`.

The last point, do not use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` because you don't know if resides in `/bin`; try using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (or `sh`) which forces the process to work under bash (sh) environment. Note that `env` exists all the time in `/usr/bin` and has all the environments (BASH, SH, TCSH...) paths registered in it.

Comment: @slhck you didn't actually edit something, you just wrote down the exact same words. I am going to flag this for moderation attention.

Comment: @Saif slhck changed those words in to monospace code items - so `#!/bin/bash` instead of #!/bin/bash - and added paragraph divisions. The post looks visually easier to parse, I see nothing wrong with this edit.

Comment: @Saif As DMA said, that was the intention. If you have a problem with this, please explain yourself on [Meta]…

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to daemonize a program that doesn't have a daemon mode then you can use [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/).  There are RPM packages for it in the [repoforge](http://repoforge.org/) repository.

Answer (score 1):

The stdout of a daemon does not go to the terminal. If you simply want to automate restarting your program, I would suggest writing a shell script to perform the exact steps you are performing manually now.

**Edit:**

Here is a simple example shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
do-start-stuff () {
    stuff-to-do
}

do-stop-stuff () {
    stuff-to-do
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        do-start-stuff
        ;;
    stop)
        do-stop-stuff
        ;;
    restart)
        do-stop-stuff
        do-start-stuff
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Can you point me in some direction on how to create a shell script.

Comment: If i create a file with the exact steps I am making, how will the script know if i want to start or stop it. Or can i work with if statements inside the file.

Comment: Yes, you can have `if` and other statements. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the help I will examine the code and I get the basic idea now. Thank you for the help. +1 for the answer.The answer of wazoox was slightly more detailed, thats why I accepted it answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to run a single app which outputs to the console, but don't want it to monopolise your terminal use screen, then detach it - type in screen, hit enter, start your app normally, then hit f6 to quit. screen -r goes back to the app